# Order of PolygonCoordinates[] is undefined in Mathematica 12?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Probably I am missing something fundamental. I try to get a polygon's ordered coordinates, but PolygonCoordinates[] yields something pretty unordered. Am I missing some essential function?

```
polygon1 = 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {0, -12}, {1, -1}, {12, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 12}, {-1,
      1}, {-12, 0}}];
Graphics[polygon1]
```

[image: correct polygon representation]

Reconstructing this same `Polygon` using `PolygonCoordinates` gives:

```
Graphics[Polygon[PolygonCoordinates[polygon1]]]
```

[image: weird polygon representation]

The same happens for `CrossingPolygon` and `WindingPolygon`.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that these tools existed. Hm. Seems to be useless, though. Why not using `polygon1[[1]]`? I cannot tell whether this is to be considered as a bug since I honestly do not understand the purpose of `PolygonCoordinates` and `CanonicalizePolygon` (the documentation is entirely usesless here). But these functions are rather new and thus may be  a bit buggy. Best if you would contact support about this.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher polygon1[[1]] works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Yes, having these new functions that behave that way is rather confusing.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In 12.0, the syntax of `Polygon` was greatly extended. It can, for example, represent multiple disjoint polygons, or polygons with holes. `poly[[1]]` may no longer give you the coordinates. Personally, I feel that by adding this complexity to such a fundamental construct as `Polygon`, we actually lost something ... I wish this extended functionality had been added to a new symbol like `CompoundPolygon` or similar.

Comment: Even in pre-12.0, Polygon could contain multiple polygons, so `poly[[1]]` is not reliable. But in 12.0, the syntax got much more complicated than that.

Comment: @Szabolcs Very good point. May way of using `Polygon` is very oldschool. ^^

Comment: According to the documentation, `CanonicalizePolygon` returns the vertices in the order that they would be returned by `Sort`, i.e. in order of increasing `x` coordinates and in order of increasing `y` coordinates in case of ties. My guess is that `PolygonCoordinates` returns them in the same order.

Comment: However, it seems that at least in the case of a convex polygon, the 'counter-clockwise' order of the coordinates can be obtained by permuting the vertices in the first entry of `CanonicalizePolygon` by the order given in the second entry. Perhaps something similar can be done for general polygons?