# PolygonCoordinates extract the submits in the "wrong" order

Tags: polygons, drawing

I don't understand why, in the example below, [`PolygonCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolygonCoordinates.html) seems unable to correctly extract the summits of a rectangle in the "right" order so we can reconstruct the same shape:

```
Rectangle[{-1,-1},{1,0}]
PolygonCoordinates[%]
Polygon[%]
```

Producing:

> ```
> Rectangle[{-1,-1},{1,0}]
> {{-1,-1},{-1,0},{1,-1},{1,0}}
> ```
>
> [image: Not a rectangle]

Obviously, the resulting polygon is not a rectangle. Why? How to fix that?

---

FWIW, there is an old, unanswered, and very similar question here:
[Order of PolygonCoordinates[] is undefined in Mathematica 12?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212650/order-of-polygoncoordinates-is-undefined-in-mathematica-12)

Comment: `Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 0}] // CanonicalizePolygon  // Normal // First` gives the coordinates in the right order. It works [in this case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215218/5467) too. The use of `First` can be found in the documentation of `PolygonCoordinates` chapter "properties & Relation", though I'm not conviced that it is reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment André. I've done some tests this afternoon. Apparently `CanonicalizePolygon` reliably produces a polygon whose submits are in the original shape order. There are even an example in the doc about converting a `Rectangle` to a `Polygon`. It's `PolygonCoordinates` that ignore the original vertice order.